# AS3/PHP - Textfield's text by email keeping the formatting, colors, etc

Tags: php, actionscript-3

My .swf is a game. When the game ends, the player can see a textual game report. This game report is generated in a Dynamic Textfield. The player can send the report by e-mail. It's easy to send the email with the report text, it works just like a form. 
The problem is that I need to keep all the colors, bolds, formatting, etc. I don't want a plain black text with no bolds, colors or formatting. So, my simple form solution doesn't work.

I'm using this simple PHP code:

```
<?php

$message = $_POST["message"];

$recipient = $_POST["email"];

utf8_decode($mensagem);

$header = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$header .= "Reply-to: ".$_POST['email']."\r\n";
$header .= "From: My swf";

$subject = "Relatorio";

$msg = "<b>Report:</b> $message\n<br />";

mail($recipient, $subject, $msg, $header);
?>
```

A friend read something about sending the text as a ByteArray, but we don't understand how to do it. I just found lots of people sending images, but we want to send text.

Thanks!

Comment: If you generated your text in the dynamic field as `htmlText`, then you could send that with the HTML intact to the PHP.

Comment: Well, it is done this way already. The text is generated as htmlText ("Render text as HTML" option marked). What may be lacking?

Comment: Got it! Thanks!
Found what I needed here:
http://kirill-poletaev.blogspot.com.br/2011/02/send-e-mail-with-html-in-it-using-as3.html
I think my mistake was that I was getting .text not .htmlText from the dynamic textField.

Comment: @Andrei Didn't you say that in you previous comment already? :p (.htmlText doesn't solve this same problem for me)

Comment: @poepje Hm? I said that the textField was marked as htmlText, but my variable wasn't getting the data as htmlText but as a simple text, which was making me lose the formatting.

Comment: Oh ok, so it was just the php where you had to change it then?

Comment: No, the AS code of the variable. From .text to .htmlText
(I don't have the code here to say exactly)

Comment: I have that too in my code, yet the link you gave here doesn't get me any further..